# StyleSheet changed my whole site

Tags: css, stylesheet

while building the basics of my website (header, footer and basic body) I was collecting the css on the various pages (header css in the header file, footer in the footer, etc) and now that I've copied and pasted everything in there it's changed the site. For example the body is now at 100% width of the page, but it is supposed to be 70% and the footer is supposed to be aligned with the body on the left, but it is about 20px to the left of where it should be, etc. You can see what im talking about at my test site http://sunnahmatch.com or by filtering through this large collection of css (if you need the html & php code let me know):

```
<style type="text/css">
#body_container{
    margin: 200px auto 0 auto;
    width:70%;
    }
.footer_inline a:active {color:#09C; text-decoration:none; font-family:GeosansLight, sans-serif; font-size:14px;}   
#header{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#333;
    }
#logo{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:left;
    }
#header_menu{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-image:url(../img/header_bg_logo.jpg);
    float:right;
    width:380px;
    height:100px;;
    }
#menu_bar{
    background:url(../img/menu_bar.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    height:42px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
#menu_text_container{
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-bottom:6px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    }

.menu_text{
    float:left;
    }
.menu_text_span{
    margin-left:30px;
    font-family: GeosansLight;
    }
.menu_text a:link {color:#FFF; text-decoration:none;font-family:GeosansLight, sans-serif; font-size:18px;}
.menu_text a:visited {color:#FFF; text-decoration:none;font-family:GeosansLight, sans-serif; font-size:18px;}
.menu_text a:hover {color:#09C; text-decoration:none;font-family:GeosansLight, sans-serif; font-size:18px;}
.menu_text a:active {color:#09C; text-decoration:none; font-family:GeosansLight, sans-serif; font-size:18px;}
.menu_text_span_top{
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    float:right;
    font-family: GeosansLight, sans-serif;
    }
.menu_text_span_top a {color:#FFF; text-decoration:none;font-family:GeosansLight, sans-serif; font-size:14px;}
.menu_text_span_top a:link {color:#FFF; text-decoration:none;font-family:GeosansLight, sans-serif; font-size:14px;}
.menu_text_span_top a:visited {color:#FFF; text-decoration:none;font-family:GeosansLight, sans-serif; font-size:14px;}
.menu_text_span_top a:hover {color:#09C; text-decoration:none;font-family:GeosansLight, sans-serif; font-size:14px;}
.menu_text_span_top a:active {color:#09C; text-decoration:none; font-family:GeosansLight, sans-serif; font-size:14px;}
.menu_text_right{
    float:right;
    }
.menu_text_span_right{
    margin-right:20px;
    float:right;
    font-family: GeosansLight;
    }
.menu_text_span_right a {color:#FFF; text-decoration:none;font-family:GeosansLight, sans-serif; font-size:14px;}
.menu_text_span_right a:link {color:#FFF; text-decoration:none;font-family:GeosansLight, sans-serif; font-size:14px;}
.menu_text_span_right a:visited {color:#FFF; text-decoration:none;font-family:GeosansLight, sans-serif; font-size:14px;}
.menu_text_span_right a:hover {color:#09C; text-decoration:none;font-family:GeosansLight, sans-serif; font-size:14px;}
.menu_text_span_right a:active {color:#09C; text-decoration:none; font-family:GeosansLight, sans-serif; font-size:14px;}
#left_container{
    float: left;
    width: 63%;
    padding:5px;
    margin-right:15px;
    background-color:#069;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px 15px;
    }
#right_container{
    float:left;
    width: 31%;
    padding:5px;
    background-color:#069;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px 15px;
    }
.column_left_tmpl{
    background-color:#FFF;
    padding:10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px 10px;
    font-family: GeosansLight, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    }
.column_right_tmpl{
    background-color:#FFF;
    padding:8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px 10px;
    font-family: GeosansLight, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;#59C169
    }
.title {
    width:100% auto;
    padding-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px;
    font-family: Arial, Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size:22px;
    color:#333;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
.spacer{
    height:5px;
    }
#header_container{
    background-color:#333;
    margin:0;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    -khtml-opacity:.9; 
    -moz-opacity:.9; 
    -ms-filter:"alpha(opacity=90)";
    filter:alpha(opacity=90);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0.9);
    opacity:.9;
    }   
#footer{
    width:70%;
    height:80px;
    float:none;
    clear:both;
    margin:0 auto;
    }   
.footer_inline{
    width:100%;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    float:left;
    font-family: GeosansLight, sans-serif;
    }
.footer_inline a {color:#FFF; text-decoration:none;font-family:GeosansLight, sans-serif; font-size:14px;}
.footer_inline a:link {color:#FFF; text-decoration:none;font-family:GeosansLight, sans-serif; font-size:14px;}
.footer_inline a:visited {color:#FFF; text-decoration:none;font-family:GeosansLight, sans-serif; font-size:14px;}
.footer_inline a:hover {color:#09C; text-decoration:none;font-family:GeosansLight, sans-serif; font-size:14px;}
</style>
```

So at which point did I go wrong, and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a separate file? And you are linking to this style sheet from within your HTML with something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/my/css/file/style.css">
```

If so take out the first line:

```
<style type="text/css">
```

and the last line:

```
</style>
```

You dont need those in a separate style sheet.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you say you aggregated all of the CSS code from every page of the site and pasted it all into one file?

How did you handle merging conflicting specifications?

For example, if two pages had two different definitions for `body` then what was your resulting definition?  Did you use both in separate blocks?  Did you use all values from both in one block?  How did you merge individual values which were different?

What you're essentially doing now is applying a lot of style specifications to pages which previously didn't have them, so it's no surprise that your site's layout has changed.

I don't know of any automated way to fix it, especially because automated tools for verifying visual things (like resulting layouts) are difficult to come by.  By aggregating all of the styles you're essentially re-styling your website.  That's going to take some manual work any way you look at it.

**Edit:** I just visited your site and noticed that your CSS file is broken anyway.  Remove the HTML `<script>` tags.  It's a CSS file, not an HTML file.

It's also standard practice to validate your markup when dealing with issues like this.  Your markup is [pretty close to valid](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://sunnahmatch.com/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), actually, which is good.  But [your CSS needs some work](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http://sunnahmatch.com/style/main.css&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en).

Comment: Yes, I'm about a week into learning css, but I did everything imaginable to avoid conflict with styles. There is only 1 body tag being used because what I am doing is using php includes for the header and footer, this makes it easier for me, and I really don't need the header and footer spidered to the best of my knowledge (correct me if I am wrong), so visually it's easier having the code separated for me, I should get in the habit of validating first and foremost when I have issues, but for some reason always forget -.- thanks for the response though!

Answer (score 2):

> I was collecting the css on the various pages (header css in the
>   header file, footer in the footer, etc) and now that I've copied and
>   pasted everything in there it's changed the site.

Looking at your CSS file, it contains the `<style>` opening and closing tag. try to remove both the first and last line in that file:

```
<style type="text/css">

...

</style>
```

You only need to have the CSS inside the `<style>` tag if your CSS rules are inside the HTML.

I hope that will solve the issue.

If that doesn't solve the issue, if you correctly copied the various css file contents **in the same order** they were loaded before, and that single CSS file is now located where the first of the others was located, then you should have the same result.

Probably you just changed the order in which the various CSS rules used to appear before, or you forget to copy something.

Also I suppose you were loading all your CSS in the same place in the `<head>` section of your website. Otherwise, chances are that some other inline style (if you have) is now overriding some rules.

You should go back to the single CSS files (you still have them, right...?) and copy them again carefully into one file.

Trying "to fix" your CSS code like you ask without having the full HTML code you had before is simply out of question.